# Is there a Sinatra style web framework for Erlang?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, frameworks, erlang, sinatra

I programmed in Ruby and Rails for quite a long time, and then I fell in love with the simplicity of the Sinatra framework which allowed me to build one page web applications.

Is there a web framework like Sinatra available for Erlang? I tried Erlyweb but it seems far too heavyweight.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could achieve something minimal with mochiweb:

```
start() ->
  mochiweb_http:start([{'ip', "127.0.0.1"}, {port, 6500},
                       {'loop', fun ?MODULE:loop/1}]).
                           % mochiweb will call loop function for each request

loop(Req) ->
  RawPath = Req:get(raw_path),
  {Path, _, _} = mochiweb_util:urlsplit_path(RawPath),   % get request path

  case Path of                                           % respond based on path
    "/"  -> respond(Req, <<"<p>Hello World!</p>">>);
    "/a" -> respond(Req, <<"<p>Page a</p>">>);
    ...
    _    -> respond(Req, <<"<p>Page not found!</p>">>)
  end.

respond(Req, Content) ->
  Req:respond({200, [{<<"Content-Type">>, <<"text/html">>}], Content}).
```

If you need advanced routing, you will have to use regex's instead of a simple case statement.

Comment: Brilliant, this is just the sort of answer I needed. Thanks! :)

Comment: Anything like this that uses websockets?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [webmachine](http://webmachine.basho.com/). It has a very simple but powerful dispatch mechanism. You simply have to write a resource module, point your URIs to it and your service is automatically HTTP compliant.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to take a look at [Axiom](https://github.com/tsujigiri/axiom) (disclosure: it's my own project). It is largely inspired by Sinatra, built on top of [Cowboy](https://github.com/extend/cowboy) and offers a lot of the features, Sinatra does.

#### A simple example:

```
-module(my_app).
-export([start/0, handle/3]).

start() ->
    axiom:start(?MODULE).

handle('GET', [<<"hi">>], _Request) ->
    <<"Hello world!">>.
```

This handles `GET /hi` and returns `Hello World!`.

Take a look at the [README](https://github.com/tsujigiri/axiom#axiom) for a documentation of it's features.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in Rusty Klophaus' [nitrogen](http://github.com/rklophaus/nitrogen) framework. It's really lightweight and is ideal for really dynamic single page sites.

Comment: Hi. Yes I have looked at nitrogen, but its still very heavyweight and seems more like fully fledged Rails, and even needs Yaws, INet, or Mochiweb installed first. I'm looking for something that allows me to serve just basic HTML (no Ajax needed) and can in few lines provide me with an application and routing ability. Sinatra lets you serve any URLs from one file, and as I understand (correct me if I'm wrong), but Nitrogen has no support for this, or at least I could not find this from the documentation on the web.

Answer (score 2):

May be this example (see REST SUPPORT) using misultin, looks like sinatra :

- http://code.google.com/p/misultin/wiki/ExamplesPage