# How to write a simple webserver in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

Using the default Erlang installation what is the minimum code needed to produce a "Hello world" producing web server?

Comment: How is this different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084639/sinatra-style-web-framework-for-erlang ?

Comment: @Zed, Zubair is asking for a minimal "hello world" server--it has a single "page" because it is minimal.  The question you linked to asks how to make a functional Web app (one-page, but responds to a variety of requests in different ways).  I assume the latter will be ajax-y.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Taking "produce" literally, here is a pretty small one. It doesn't even read the request (but does fork on every request, so it's not as minimal possible).

```
-module(hello).
-export([start/1]).

start(Port) ->
    spawn(fun () -> {ok, Sock} = gen_tcp:listen(Port, [{active, false}]), 
                    loop(Sock) end).

loop(Sock) ->
    {ok, Conn} = gen_tcp:accept(Sock),
    Handler = spawn(fun () -> handle(Conn) end),
    gen_tcp:controlling_process(Conn, Handler),
    loop(Sock).

handle(Conn) ->
    gen_tcp:send(Conn, response("Hello World")),
    gen_tcp:close(Conn).

response(Str) ->
    B = iolist_to_binary(Str),
    iolist_to_binary(
      io_lib:fwrite(
         "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/html\nContent-Length: ~p\n\n~s",
         [size(B), B])).
```

Comment: See `{packet, http}` for `Options` of `gen_tcp:listen` for decoding HTTP headers.

Comment: I was looking at this code, and even though it looks clean, I found an issue. When testing it with Apache Bench, I get a `apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (104)`. it works fine when accessing in a browser, or using curl. Do you have any idea why this is?

Comment: @MartinKristiansen Remove the line `gen_tcp:close(Conn).`

Comment: @FelixLange Thanks for this answer Felix.. Could you please explain the code written. It will be very helpful for erlang enthusiasts like me :-)

Comment: The last `iolist_to_binary/1` in `response/1` is unnecessary.

Comment: if we starting server only once then why we need to `spawn spawn(fun () -> {ok, Sock} = gen_tcp:listen(Port, [{active, false}]), 
                    loop(Sock) end).`  it is understandable at handler to give every request a new process. if we want to start one server at a time still we need to spawn above tcp:listen

Answer (score 11):

For a web server using only the built in libraries check out [inets http_server](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/inets/http_server.html).
When in need of some more power but still with simplicity you should check out the [mochiweb](https://github.com/mochi/mochiweb) library. You can google for loads of example code.

Comment: Thats great, so using INets can I write a single module webserver?

Answer (score 8):

Another way, similar to the `gen_tcp` example above but with less code and already offered as a suggestion, is using the [inets library](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/inets/http_server.html).

```
%%%
%%% A simple "Hello, world" server in the Erlang.
%%%

-module(hello_erlang).
-export([
  main/1,
  run_server/0,
  start/0
]).

main(_) ->
  start(),
  receive
    stop -> ok
  end.

run_server() ->
  ok = inets:start(),
  {ok, _} = inets:start(httpd, [
    {port, 0},
    {server_name, "hello_erlang"},
    {server_root, "/tmp"},
    {document_root, "/tmp"},
    {bind_address, "localhost"}
  ]).

start() -> run_server().
```

Keep in mind, this exposes your `/tmp` directory.

To run, simply:

```
$ escript ./hello_erlang.erl
```

Answer (score 7):

Do you actually want to write a web server in Erlang, or do you want an Erlang web server so that you can create dynamic web content using Erlang?

If the latter, try [YAWS](http://yaws.hyber.org/).  If the former, have a look at the [YAWS source code](http://github.com/klacke/yaws) for inspiration

Comment: I want to make dynamic content, but just wanted to know the bare minimum needed for a web server. I looked at the Yaws source code and my first impression was that alot of code was needed.

Answer (score 4):

For a very easy to use webserver for building restful apps or such check out the gen_webserver behaviour: http://github.com/martinjlogan/gen_web_server.

Answer (score 1):

Just one fix for Felix's answer and it addresses the issues Martin is seeing. Before closing a socket, all data being sent from the client should be received (using for example `do_recv` from [gen_tcp description](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html)).

Otherwise there's a race condition for the browser/proxy sending the HTTP request being quick enough to send the http request before the socket is closed.