# How to get the URL in Erlang?

Tags: parameters, request, erlang

I want to show different Strings on the Web page according to the URL query string parameter.

For example if the URL is `localhost:8080?x=a` then the web page will show "Hello" and when the URL is `localhost:8080?x=b` then the web page will show "Bye".

The problem here I am facing is how to get the query parameters.

Answer (score 2):

First using [http_uri:parse/1](http://erlang.org/doc/man/http_uri.html) you can parse your URI.

```
{ok, Result} = http_uri:parse("http://localhost:8080?x=a"),
{Scheme, UserInfo, Host, Port, Path, Query} = Result,
```

It captures the query string and stores it in `Query` Variable.

Then a simple way to get the value of `x` parameter in the URI query string is using pattern matching.

```
"?x=" ++ Param = Query,
```

**Note** that in case of presence of other keys in the query string this match might fail, because it expects just a query string with one key which must be `x`.

Now you can use a case expression to find out what is inside `Param` variable and act upon it.

```
case Param of
   "a" -> "Hello";
   "b" -> "Bye"
end
```

Comment: @SunnyJain and what is the doubt about?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how do I get the url to pass as the argument in http_uri:parse/1.

Comment: @SunnyJain What HTTP framework are you using and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've just started using Erlang and I just want to create a basic server which can handle the above functionality. I m creating the server using the command :

**{ok, Pid} = inets:start(httpd, [{port, 0},
      {server_name,"httpd_test"}, {server_root,"/tmp"},
      {document_root,"/tmp/htdocs"}, {bind_address, "localhost"}]).**

which I read from this [link](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/inets/http_server.html).

Comment: @SunnyJain I suggest to use this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206933/how-to-write-a-simple-webserver-in-erlang) and if you can't get your way through ask a detailed question about it.