# Handling HTTP Requests and Responses

Tags: http, api, erlang

What is the best erlang library for processing http requests and responses from within an erlang application?  I have taken a look at inets but as a standalone application, it seems more like a replacement for curl.

I would like to access external APIs from within the erlang application so would need to parse responses and be able to make subsequent requests with cookies generated from the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [mochiweb](http://code.google.com/p/mochiweb/) and [misultin](http://code.google.com/p/misultin/). [A nice tutorial](http://beebole.com/en/blog/erlang/tutorial-web-application-erlang/) on mochiweb. There are also [other applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084639/sinatra-style-web-framework-for-erlang).

Answer (score 2):

What's the problem with inets (or curl for that matter)? The alternative http client is ibrowse which you can find on github.

If you need to parse the html, there's an html parser that comes as part of the http server toolkit, mochiweb. Mochiweb also comes with a json parser.